# Subir archivo y renombrarlo

Tags: php, imagen

Buenas tardes.
Deseo subir un archivo a mi servidor pero que se renombre con el nombre de una variable que viene por método `GET`, es decir, la dirección sería `localhost/fotos/subir.php?nuevonombre=juan`, y si el archivo se llama `Felipe.jpg`, deseo que se renombre y se llame `juan.jpg`.

Aquí adjunto el código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Subir archivos al servidor</title>
    <meta name ="author" content ="Norfi Carrodeguas">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body{font-size:1.2em;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='post'>
    <input name='uploadedfile' type='file'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Subir archivo'>
    </form>
    <?php 
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
    { 
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>El archivo ". basename(             
    $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " ha sido subido</span><br>";
    }else{
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error, trate de nuevo!";
    } 
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Así como tienes tu código funciona ? Es decir captura la img y la guarda en la carpeta ?

Comment: ¿ Por qué no envía el nuevo nombre también en el `form` ?  , es decir el ejemplo se entiende, pero si son más de 1 archivo , ¿será el mismo nombre? ¿ Quizá sería necesario valores aleatorios para el nombre?

Comment: Camilo, como esta el código el sube la imagen y la guarda correctamente, lo que no hace es renombrarlo y eso también lo deseo realizar.

Comment: Joel siempre será un sólo archivo.

Comment: Prueba entonces cambiando esta línea $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);  por $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_GET['nuevonombre']); y me cuentas, no lo publico como respuesta por que no estoy 100% seguro

Comment: Camilo si lo renombre, pero no pone la extensión, es decir le pone juan, pero no .jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción para renombrar sería, obtener primero la extensión del archivo haciendo uso de [explode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) , con la diferencia que se accederá a `name` y no a `tmp_name` ya que la extensión de `tmp_name` es `tmp`.

```
 $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
 end($parts) // Obtiene el ultimo elemento del array devuelto por explode.
```

Para luego simplemente concatenar el nombre que recibe. Hay que tener en cuenta que sería mejor un campo oculto *(hidden)* en el `dom` con el nuevo nombre y no realizar `_GET` Y `_POST` al mismo tiempo.

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='post'>
  <input type="hidden" name="nuevonombre" value="juan">
  <input name='uploadedfile' type='file'><br>
  <input type='submit' value='Subir archivo'>
</form>

<?php
  $target_path = "uploads/";
  $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
  //construimos el nuevo nombre con lo que viene por post nuevonombre
 // con el final del explode que sería la extensión de la imagen
  $target_path = $target_path . $_POST['nuevonombre'] .".". end($parts);

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
  { 
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>El archivo ". basename(             
    $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " ha sido subido</span><br>";
  }
   else{
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error, trate de nuevo!";
  }
```

Comment: Me funciona con letras, pero cuando envío números no, es decir si la variable nuevonombre=123, no renombra el archivo sino que lo guarda con el nombre con que lo subió.

Comment: Ya solucione el problema, simplemente tenias un error en el código que dices que se recibe por POST, cuando en realidad es por GET.

Comment: @FredyAristizábalAristizábal sí, detalle eso en mi respuesta  que sería mejor un campo `hidden` . Verifique espero le ayude.

Comment: Mil gracias por tu ayuda. Fue perfecta tu ayuda.